# Searching objects in django

Tags: python, django

Please help, because I'm confused.
I'm using Django 1.11 and python 3.5. 
Trying to get values, and when getting via "contains" everything is working, but when i trying iexact function use, have all the time wrong response. Why?

Examples :

```
>>> print(Blog.objects.filter(title__contains='Django'))
<QuerySet [<Blog: 1>, <Blog: 4>]>
>>> print(Blog.objects.filter(title__iexact='Django'))
<QuerySet []>
```

or

```
>>> print(Blog.objects.get(title__contains='Django'))
1
>>> print(Blog.objects.get(title__iexact='Django'))
...
blog.models.DoesNotExist: Blog matching query does not exist.
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you want `icontains`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exact` and `contains` are quite different. We could say `exact` is a subset of `contains`.

Your `title` field could *contain* `'Django'`, but the title itself isn't `'Django'`, so `exact` or `iexact` fails.

e.g.

```
title = 'Django: the framework for perfectionists with deadlines'
```

Works for `contains` but fails for `[i]exact`.

If you're looking for case-insentive containment, then `icontains` is what you want.

Comment: Oh I got it
But how I can get objects which contains something but ignoring case? is it possible?

Comment: You're brilliant